# How to add custom css to blank/errors fields in jQuery validation plugin?

Tags: jquery, forms, validation

Sorry to ask this type of question but i'm very new to `jQuery validation plugin`

The plugin is doing all good, but I want that all those input fields having **errors/blank** should have a **red  border**,
 how to achieve this through `jQuery validation plugin`

Comment: By default jQuery validate adds a class of `error` to fields which are invalid, so you can just put whatever styling you need on that class.

Comment: as pointed out @RoryMcCrossan use **css** `.error{ border: 1px solid red; }`

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan: Yes i did this but it is not applying class to the blank input fields. only the label tags are appearing red

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for something like this: [See DEMO](http://www.websitecodetutorials.com/code/jquery-plugins/jquery-validation-demo.php)

The code is here: [Example Code](http://www.websitecodetutorials.com/code/jquery-plugins/jquery-validation.php)

JS:

```
/* Fire Valaidate */
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#form").validate({
      rules: {
         name: {
            required: true
               }
         },
         messages: {
            name: "Required Field"
         }
     });
});
```

CSS:

```
#form label.error {
    color:red;
}
#form input.error {
    border:1px solid red;
}
```

HTML:

```
<form id="form" method="" action="">
    <label for="name">Name</label>
   <input type="text" id="name" name="name">
</form>
```